# Moving data from one table to another table on a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to copy a few rows from one table to a table on a different server. The table structures the same in both. People mentioned using a trigger but that wouldn't work for my solution.

We could create a script but it's going to be done several times, and that adds to much risk. Any other options?

Edit: We aren't able to do Linked Servers :(

Comment: Replication, mirroring, sql jobs...

Comment: Why does running a script several times create too much risk?

Comment: Is the Import and Export wizard also not an option?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The import and export wizard is an option but we'll be doing this for over 400 databases so it would be pretty time consuming. Scripting it out would add too much risk because we'd need to verify the data. There's quite a few columns and it would take a long time.

Comment: I think there is like a command line version of Linked Server.

Comment: In that case (400+ DBs), it sounds like a job for Integration Services (or - as mentioned earlier by @GiorgiNakeuri - replication, mirroring, sql jobs...)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [OPENDATASOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856(v=sql.100).aspx) or [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.100).aspx)?

You basically connect to a server in TSQL.
It is like an on the fly Linked Server.

Answer (score 1):

If your servers are in the same network look at [SQL Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Yeah we can't do Linked servers :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use linked servers or OPENROWSET, then scripts is still a viable option!  IMO, simplest thing is to BCP out the required data from the first server, and BCP back into the other server.  This is assuming it's the same schema/rows across all 400 dbs/servers, because once you do it for one object, it's should be able to execute on any other server very easily.  Not sure what the risk is you are referring to, feel free to expand on it.